# Special characters in CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, special-characters

What characters can be used as CSS identifiers in a CSS file?

How can special characters be escaped (to avoid conflicts)?

Comment: This question is waaaaay too simplistic to have a correct answer. The accepted answer only answers one aspect of "special characters" - that is, what characters are allowed in idents. It doesn't account for any other part of the Selectors grammar (or CSS grammar, for that matter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element
>   names, classes, and IDs in selectors)
>   can contain only the characters
>   [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters
>   U+00A1 and higher, plus the hyphen (-)
>   and the underscore (_); they cannot
>   start with a digit, or a hyphen
>   followed by a digit. Identifiers can
>   also contain escaped characters and
>   any ISO 10646 character as a numeric
>   code (see next item).code (see next item).

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

Answer (score 6):

Normally, you wouldn't need to escape any special characters in CSS.  This is because most CSS selector characters (`., >, +, ~, #, :, etc`) are not valid in id attributes or tag names, and they are rarely used in class names.

The only notable exception is a namespaced element in the form `<ns:tagName>`, which is more commonly seen in Internet Explorer.  To target those elements, you can escape the `:` character.  For example, VML objects have their behavior defined as follows:

```
v\:* { behavior: url(#default#vml); }
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this, I've just inherited some CSS with some unusual characters in the selector (in this instance, a + character in an ID), and a blackslash does escape it correctly as per above

Comment: Note that HTML5 allows any character in ID attributes except for whitespace, no escaping necessary.  To reference these from CSS, you would need to escape certain characters that aren't valid in a CSS identifier.  [Details of that escaping here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).