# How to handle an id tag with '.' in CSS

Tags: css, syntax, css-selectors

My problem is that I don't have the HTML code to change the id's to remove the '.'...

Is it possible to handle such id's, lets say:

```
<td id='my.id'>
```

In the CSS file to do something like:

```
#[my.id]{ ... }
```

I know this doesn't work (that's more access approach), but I wonder if there's a syntax for this in CSS?

Comment: Whoever wrote that CSS needs to be slapped.

Comment: you may want to *accept* the answer that worked for you. (Click the check mark by the question)

Comment: @Nivas , For some reason i need to wait for 2 mins..... i will the moment i can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `#my\.id` it the CSS.

I'm not sure if it works on all browsers though. I'd recommend avoiding dots in id's

Answer (score 1):

Use "\" to escape special characters.

For

```
        <div id="id.id">Red Color</div>
```

Use

```
        #id\.id
        {
            color: red;
        }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132793/special-characters-in-css-selectors) question is perhaps related.

Answer (score 1):

This, surprisingly to me, works.  I have only tested this in Chrome.

```
<style>
#my\.id {
 color:red;
} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash before the dot:

```
#my\.id
{
    color: red;
    border: 1px dashed #f00;
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/6wecj/) for you :)

Answer (score -2):

It is not allowed to use a DOT in a selector as far as I know :)

Comment: it is very much allowed as per the html specs: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").